# Doctrine Pagination Using Raw SQL

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, pagination

How can we do Doctrine_Pager with Raw Sql?

Something Like

```
$query = "Select * from some_table";

$pager = new Doctrine_Pager();
```

I am unable to use Doctrine_Query::create() because the query is pretty complex.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Which Doctrine version are you using?